# How do I deploy my Gatsby site to Azure when new Prismic content is published?

Tags: azure, gatsby, webhooks, prismic.io

My current workflow sucks! It's due to inexperience with static site generators. I have a site built with Gatsby. The content is sourced from the Prismic headless CMS. I deploy to Azure Static Web Apps via command line Git. When I push or manually run a Github Action, the site grabs all the content from Prismic, builds and deploys. You have to first publish in Prismic, then open up Github and run the actions.

Prismic has a webhook option. You give it an API endpoint and auth credentials and whatever is at the other end gets executed when content is published. I also have an API endpoint set up in Azure but it does nothing right now but return a string when you access it.

How do I bridge the two so the site builds and redeploys whenever content is published at Prismic?

Answer (score 1):

This is totally feasible (I didn't try it myself) but needs some configurations.
To do this you need to use Github Actions

using Github Actions require users to add a personal access token with the repo scope key.  To learn more refer to Github's [docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create-a-repository-dispatch-event).

You need to add the header key & value in your Prismic Webhooks settings such as

[image]

**Note:** Currently, the custom headers feature is in the testing phase and it will be released soon check [this page](https://portal.productboard.com/dy3xgwivwydsw7gltxfso9gs/c/110-custom-webhook-headers) to follow the progress of the feature.

Also, you can check this [article](https://www.contentful.com/blog/2020/06/01/running-static-site-builds-with-github-actions-and-contentful/) article to get some inspiration, and it will be cool if you can share your work with the community.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm going to give this a shot and make tweaks where needed. I'll let you know how it works out.